# Spartacus Loader Meta Reducer - Product Search

Tags: angular, ngrx, reducers, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to incorporate a loading spinner when loading and navigating between the PLP pages.

I see in the documentation that this behavior is facilitated by `loaderReducer`, but the main drawback I have is that I do not have access to the product reducers.

I can create a custom actions extending the `StateUtils.EntityLoadAction` and getting the loading boolean in the store but whith the custom reducer for `product > search` I lose the reducer for:

- `product > details`
- `product > reviews`
- `product > references`

Since I don't have access to them and im replacing the reducer for `PRODUCT_FEATURE = 'product'`

[Screenshot Product Reducer Spartacus 2.1.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDEoJ.png)

1. Reducer that I want and can replace
2. The reducers that I lose

Does anyone know a work around ?

**Spartacus version: 2.1.x**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally it's not trivial to extend ngrx reducer and state, as it basically requires to create new reducer, state shape, selecors, actions and use them in custmosed facades.
I would not go this route.

For you specific case I would consider exposing loading flag just by observing *ProductSearchAction*s, like SearchProducts, SearchProductsSuccess, SearchProductsFail. It looks like much more simpler approach that should give you exactly the same information without the overhead of extending the store.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @dunqan !
I agree with your recommendation. 

For this scenario where I only want to show/detect a loading status in the PLP, I add as a comment that detecting the value of the property "auxiliary", equal to true (of the search action), the actions dispatched by the search box can be excluded.
Thus avoiding the spinner when writing in the search box.